# Why am I getting this Hashmap output?

Tags: java, collections, hashmap

```java
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Map {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub

       int arr[] = {10, 3, 34, 3, 10};

       HashMap<Integer, Integer> hmap=new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

       for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
           System.out.println(hmap.put(arr[i], 1));
       }
   }
}
```

I am getting the output as below:

```
null
null
null
1
1
```

I am not getting why am I getting the output as three times `null` and two times one.

Comment: why initially its giving an output as null

Comment: Because the `put()` function is [defined to return the old value associated with the key](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#put-K-V-).

Comment: @Andy Thomas,It would be great if you explain some more..

Comment: What did you expect it to print, and why? Did you read documentation of [`put()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#put-K-V-) to understand what it returns?

Comment: @Andreas i am expecting it to show 1 ,1

Comment: Why? You are calling it 5 times, so why not expect 5 outputs?

Comment: @Andreas,you are right but question remains why 3 null values

Comment: @Swati - because you told it to print them. System.out.println( Object ) prints the value of `String.valueOf( Object )`, which is [defined to be "null" for a null reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf-java.lang.Object-). You got null values back from your first three put() calls because there was no prior value associated with those keys. Don't guess at the behavior of methods. Read the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am not getting why am i getting the output as "three times null and
>   two times one".

to understand the reasoning behind the behaviour you'll need to read the java specification on the put method.

[**put(K key, V value)**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#put(K,%20V))

> returns the previous value associated with key, or null if there was no
>   mapping for key.

what you want is this:

```
int arr[] = {10,3,34,3,10};

HashMap<Integer,Integer> hmap = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
     hmap.put(arr[i],1);
}

hmap.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println("key = " + k + " value = " + v));
```

output:

```
key = 34 value = 1
key = 3 value = 1
key = 10 value = 1
```

if you're wondering why not all the keys within the `arr` array are printed, the reason behind this is simply because:

> [**put(K key, V value)**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#put(K,%20V)) associates the specified value with the
>   specified key in this map. If the map previously contained a mapping
>   for the key, the old value is replaced.

To put it simply, **[HashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)** key is unique, if any duplicate key is to be added then it will be overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

The `put` function of the `Hashmap` inserts the value in the Hashmap, and if the key already exists, it replaces the old value of the key with the new one and returns the previous value associated with key, or `null` if there was no mapping for key. When you insert first three values i.e. 10,3,34 since they do not exist in the `Hashmap`, so `null` is returned, but for when you insert 3 again,this key already exists, so `put` replaces the old value and returns the old value for the same key which is 1,l so it prints 1. Similar for 10.

Comment: And here you can find documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#put(K,%20V)